# php show specific data in popup

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an online registration system. I have made an unordered list to display a new pending applicants awaiting approval or rejection. I have also added a button for each new applicant to show their data from the pending table.

The problem is when I add more than one applicants, it only shows the last applicant's details for all of them. I have been through this for hours, yet days and nothing works.

This is my code from the page that has the unordered list:

```
function getStudent () {
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pending_students_table WHERE status IS NULL;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $i = 1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $sId = $row['id'];
        $sName = $row['student_name'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

        echo "<tr id='sNew".$i."'>";
        echo "<td>".$i." - </td>";
        echo "<td>{$sName}</td>";
        echo "<td><button type='submit' name='sAcc' value='{$sId}'>Accept</button></td>";
        echo "<td><button type='submit' name='sRej' value='{$sId}'>Reject</button></td>";
        echo "<td><button name='stInfo' value='{$sId}'><a href='student_information.php?id=<?php echo ".'"$row[$id]"'."; ?>' target='_blank' style='color: #000000; text-decoration: none;' onClick='pop_up(this)'>Student Details</a></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $i++;
        }


}
```

And this is the code from student_information.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('partials/connectDb.php');

echo "<h2>Student Information</h2>";

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT pending_students_table.id, pending_students_table.student_name,
        pending_students_table.student_email, pending_students_table.student_phone,
        major_table.major_name, pending_students_table.student_password,
        pending_students_table.high_school_major, pending_students_table.high_school_gpa,
        pending_students_table.adviser, pending_students_table.status 
        FROM pending_students_table INNER JOIN major_table ON pending_students_table.student_major = major_table.major_id WHERE pending_students_table.id = '$id';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sId = $row['id'];
    $sName = $row['student_name'];
    $sPhone = $row['student_phone'];
    $sMajor = $row['major_name'];
    $sHsMajor = $row['high_school_major'];
    $sHsGpa = $row['high_school_gpa'];

    $sHsMajorString = '';

    if ($sHsMajor == 1) {
        $sHsMajorString = 'Commercial';
    } elseif ($sHsMajor == 2) {
        $sHsMajorString = 'Literature';
    } elseif ($sHsMajor == 3) {
        $sHsMajorString = 'Science';
    } elseif ($sHsMajor == 4) {
        $sHsMajorString = '(Institute of Technology)';
    }

    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>Name: {$sName}</li>";
    echo "<li>Phone: {$sPhone}</li>";
    echo "<li>Selected Major: {$sMajor}</li>";
    echo "<li>High School Major: {$sHsMajorString}</li>";
    echo "<li>High School GPA: {$sHsGpa}</li>";
    echo "</ul>";


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Link to the student_information.php you use inline PHP code, but your are already in the parsed area.
So you don't have to use `href='student_information.php?id=<?php echo ".'"$row[$id]"'."; ?>' target='_blank'`, you can use `href='student_information.php?id=$row['id']' target='_blank'`.

Changed Code:

```
function getStudent () {
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pending_students_table WHERE status IS NULL;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $i = 1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $sId = $row['id'];
        $sName = $row['student_name'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

        echo "<tr id='sNew".$i."'>";
        echo "<td>".$i." - </td>";
        echo "<td>{$sName}</td>";
        echo "<td><button type='submit' name='sAcc' value='{$sId}'>Accept</button></td>";
        echo "<td><button type='submit' name='sRej' value='{$sId}'>Reject</button></td>";
        echo "<td><button name='stInfo' value='{$sId}'><a href='student_information.php?id=".$row['id']."' target='_blank' style='color: #000000; text-decoration: none;' onClick='pop_up(this)'>Student Details</a></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $i++;
        }


}
```

Also you should use `$id = $_GET['id'];` instead of `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`, because `$_SESSION['id'];` will always contain the last ID.

Changed Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('partials/connectDb.php');

echo "<h2>Student Information</h2>";

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT pending_students_table.id, pending_students_table.student_name,
        pending_students_table.student_email, pending_students_table.student_phone,
        major_table.major_name, pending_students_table.student_password,
        pending_students_table.high_school_major, pending_students_table.high_school_gpa,
        pending_students_table.adviser, pending_students_table.status 
        FROM pending_students_table INNER JOIN major_table ON pending_students_table.student_major = major_table.major_id WHERE pending_students_table.id = '$id';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sId = $row['id'];
    $sName = $row['student_name'];
    $sPhone = $row['student_phone'];
    $sMajor = $row['major_name'];
    $sHsMajor = $row['high_school_major'];
    $sHsGpa = $row['high_school_gpa'];

    $sHsMajorString = '';

    if ($sHsMajor == 1) {
        $sHsMajorString = 'Commercial';
    } elseif ($sHsMajor == 2) {
        $sHsMajorString = 'Literature';
    } elseif ($sHsMajor == 3) {
        $sHsMajorString = 'Science';
    } elseif ($sHsMajor == 4) {
        $sHsMajorString = '(Institute of Technology)';
    }

    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>Name: {$sName}</li>";
    echo "<li>Phone: {$sPhone}</li>";
    echo "<li>Selected Major: {$sMajor}</li>";
    echo "<li>High School Major: {$sHsMajorString}</li>";
    echo "<li>High School GPA: {$sHsGpa}</li>";
    echo "</ul>";


}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I updated the link as you described and used $id = $_GET['id']; and now it works like a charm! :D

Answer (score 0):

You use $_SESSION['id'] in students_information.php which is always the last queried student.

Solution:

Use your $_GET variable:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Second problem:

When creating your link you add another pair of ' which are not needed. So either replace them as suggested in my comment or use

```
str_replace("'","")
```

Comment: I used it and made the data disappear!

Comment: Did the url really contain a valid id? Because if not this code will throw out nothing.

Comment: Change <a href='student_information.php?id=<?php echo "."$row[$id]"."; ?>'

Comment: I used that and still doesn't work. It gives me "undefined index" error!

Comment: Please comment how the link from student_information looks like.

Comment: A small window (as popup) that display header "Student Information" above, and supposed to be displaying the specific data below, but there is nothing...

Comment: I get that part. What url (yoursite.com) is displayed when hovering above it ? Is it student_information.php?id='123' or student_information.php?id=123

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, i don't think it would be wise to send session of user just for the sake of approving or disapproving. This might make your database vulnerable to approving or rejecting wrong result because at some instance you might forget to unset the session.

I would recommend you use **$_POST** or **$_GET**.

For instance in your question, i would change

this `$id = $_SESSION['id'];` in the student_information.php page to `$id = $_GET['id'];`

and also correct your codes at the links, some of the code are not correct

For instance, in your code, i see you echo inside another echo which is not recommended, and also you are adding another `<?php` syntax inside another syntax `<?php`, also not recommended.

i.e. this line

```
echo "<td><button name='stInfo' value='{$sId}'><a href='student_information.php?id=<?php echo ".'"$row[$id]"'."; ?>' target='_blank' style='color: #000000; text-decoration: none;' onClick='pop_up(this)'>Student Details</a></button></td>";
```

Try to replace this part

```
<a href='student_information.php?id=<?php echo ".'"$row[$id]"'."; ?>...
```

to something like this

```
<a href='student_information.php?id=".$sId.".....
```

And in your student_informtion.php page. since you are displaying only one student, i don't see the reason for trying to display a list. i.e. this part

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {....
```

Hope this would be of some help